# How to get file_id of individual documents in a grouped document message in telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Suppose a user sends a grouped document message  to my bot,
[Click to see the image of a telegram media message group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6y3U.png)
then which fields of that [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) type  should I use to get the file ID of all the individual documents in that grouped document message?
What do I actually do to get the list of those file_id?

I searched different field in the [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message).
The Message type has media_group_id (attribute) which is "The unique identifier of a media message group this message belongs to"

but I am not sure if that attribute is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Media groups are just a nice visual representation of a group of several messages. Each message will contain only one document.