# file_id of individual media in a Grouped Media in telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

When a user sends a grouped media (let's say three PDF files grouped together) to a Telegram bot, the [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object corresponding to this grouped Media has only the file_id of the first file,  but we can't obtain the file_id of the rest of the files in the grouped media.

The [Message object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) does have the media_group_id, but this ID can't be used to extract file_id of other rest documents/media.

[@CallMeStag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10606962/callmestag) suggested in his [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76194627/21809309) that grouped media is just several messages, but on using Python debugger also, in fact, I found a grouped media is received as a single Message object, not multiple Message followed by one another.

```py
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY, parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg_file: True)
def grouped_media_handler(msg_file):
    print(msg_file.document.file_id)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg_file, grouped_media_handler)

keep_alive.keep_alive()
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Ideally, This function should print all the file_id of the documents, if grouped media were just several messages. But, the function is called only once (for the first document)